# Find entire row in R data frame?

Tags: r, search, dataframe, design-patterns

I have a large dataframe `df` with 10 columns.

For example:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 ......
a    22   13   dd   kuku ppp
q    123  444  dff  pupu sds
```

I get a new record rec1 with the same structure (10 columns):

```
rec1 <-  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 ......
         a    22   13   dd   kuku ppp
```

I want to search df and return true/false if I have found this row or not.
Please advise how to do this? Dplyr filter?

Comment: Please clarify: Do all columns of the rows have to match?

Comment: Yes but the can be in different order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# sample data
df = mtcars
my_row = mtcars[10,]
```

Option 1: Use apply to find a row that matches all values in your row.

```
any(apply(df,1,function(x) {all(x==my_row)}))
```

Option 2: create an index by pasting all columns per row, then match against that.

```
index = do.call("paste", mtcars)
do.call('paste',my_row) %in% index
```

Both return `TRUE`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use `row.match` from the `prodlim` package.

```
!is.na(row.match(rec1, df))
```

A bit of a workaround with a **dplyr::semi_join**. And then check if there are more than 0 rows.

```
require(dplyr)

nrow(semi_join(df, rec1)) > 0
```